# Can't force page to scroll to top on refresh on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

i'm trying to force the page to scroll to top on refresh with something similar to this

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

But it seems to happen before the automatic scroll down on refresh. My script runs and then the browser restores its last position.

I'm running the code in several places like this

```
        $(function(){
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });

        $(window).scrollTop(0);

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });

        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
```

BUt the same happens all the time. Do I have to put this code somewhere else? Load the JS in a specific part of the HTML? Is there anything else on pure JS or jQuery that could help me with this issue?

@Edit

I tried with `$(html, body).scrollTo(0)` and couldnt make it work

I tried without jQuery and nothing happened

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

I disabled everything I had written with Javascript and put only this piece of code and nothing happens.

@edit2

I've had this problem before and I'm sure i 'solved' this with a `setTimeout`, as suggested by @raam86. The problem is that I do some math when page loads and this must be done before the user starts scrolling up and down

Comment: Apply `scrollTop()` on `html, body` instead of `window`.

Comment: no. still scrolling down. not sure if it is ignoring the code or if the browser scrolls down after the page refresh. I don't use any other script that scrolls the page

Answer (score 15):

Correct answer is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

Because Chrome and others browsers "remember" the last scroll position before unloading, so if you set the value to 0,0 just before the unload of your page they will remember of 0,0 and won't scroll back to where the scrollbar was :)

Just past that on all the page's controllers and they will scroll to top on reload/refresh/others

Answer (score 0):

Try using set timeout.

something like:

```
var _TIMEOUT = 300
setTimeout(function(){$(window).scrollTo(0)},_TIMEOUT );
```

This will hopefully be triggered after chrome scrolling. if it doesn't try fiddling with the timeout

Comment: yea this should work but I make some Math when page loads, I'll have to modify it all (because it must be ready for the users when they scroll down and up)